# How to Avoid create two instance of a fragment in use of ViewPager Android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I made an Tabbed View activity that has two tab and of course two fragments. 
I need to set Tag for each fragment because I want to send data  to them and I should know If they have been created ([according to Deliver a message to Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#Deliver))

But I have a problem. at the moment I created a new instance of my fragment in getItem method and set a Tag to it in order to detect this fragment in another place (getCurrencies method) to send data to it. but in getItem I have to create another instance of my fragment and return it and here is the problem!
I have to create two instance of fragment! please look at the below code and you will find out.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    List < CurrencyModel > currencies;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        getCurrencies();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


    }




    public void getCurrencies() {

        APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
        Call < GetCurrenciesModel > call = apiInterface.getCurrencies();
        call.enqueue(new Callback < GetCurrenciesModel > () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < GetCurrenciesModel > call, Response < GetCurrenciesModel > response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    if (response.body().getStatus() == true) {
                        currencies = new ArrayList < CurrencyModel > ();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getCurrencies().size(); i++) {

                            currencies.add(response.body().getCurrencies().get(i));


                        }

                        FeesFragment fragment = (FeesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FEESFRAGMENT");
                        if (fragment != null) {

                            fragment.caller(currencies);
                        } else {

                            FeesFragment feesFragment = new FeesFragment();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Curren", (ArrayList << ? extends Parcelable > ) currencies);
                            feesFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                            transaction.replace(R.id.fees_fragment_view, feesFragment);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            // Commit the transaction
                            transaction.commit();


                        }



                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call < GetCurrenciesModel > call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });



    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {}

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    return new ExchangeFragment();

                case 1:
                    Fragment feesFragment = new FeesFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fees_fragment_view, feesFragment, "FEESFRAGMENT");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return new FeesFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am checking the FragmentManager for fragment instances before creating new ones. I tag each fragment instance when the PagerAdapter needs them and am searching through the FragmentManager for existing instances before instantiating new ones. Here is the code that I am using.

PagerAdapter class:

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    private PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" +
                viewPager.getId() + ":" + getItemId(position));

        if (fragment != null) {
            return fragment;
        } else {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return FinderOrganizationsFragment.newInstance();
                case 1:
                    return FinderUsersFragment.newInstance();
                case 2:
                    return FinderBusinessesFragment.newInstance();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
}
```

newInstance method in each Fragment used in ViewPager:

```
public static FinderOrganizationsFragment newInstance() {
    return new FinderOrganizationsFragment();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but I didn't get how can I find the initiated fragment in where I want to pass it my data. Could you show it in my codes?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. Do you want to find the created fragment in the PagerAdapter by tag or pass it data while you are creating it? Or do you want to pass data to the created fragment after it has been created? It may be best to create more posts asking these questions after searching through any similar ones you may find on the site.